# Python optimize data structure

Tags: python, data-structures

I failed in an interview problem solving. They presented a json object:

```
{
    "UserName": "Tom Las",
    "title": "Director"
},
{
    "UserName": "Mike Sea",
    "title": "senior manager"
},
{
    "UserName": "Jojo Lee",
    "title": "manager",
    "direct Report": "Mike Sea"
},
{
    "UserName": "Luke Shi",
    "title": "manager",
    "direct Report": "Mike Sea"
},
{
    "UserName": "Bob Aeo",
    "title": "engineer",
    "direct Report": "Luke Shi"
},
{
    "UserName": "Zobu hu",
    "title": "engineer",
    "direct Report": "Tom Las"
}
```

Require a formated output of organization structure like:

```
Mike Sea - senior manager
  Jojo Lee
  Luke Shi
    Bob Aeo
Tom Las - Director
  Zobu hu
```

**Here is my solution.** I use two dictionary to track leader and team member information and use " "*n to indent team member in sub team. I feel below code is clumsy and not flexible to show more levels of sub team, for example if "Bob Aeo" also has team member under him. Should i consider different data structure instead of dictionary in this case? Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from collections import defaultdict

MemberInfo = [
    {
        "UserName": "Tom Las",
        "title": "Director"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Mike Sea",
        "title": "senior manager"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Jojo Lee",
        "title": "manager",
        "direct Report": "Mike Sea"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Luke Shi",
        "title": "manager",
        "direct Report": "Mike Sea"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Bob Aeo",
        "title": "engineer",
        "direct Report": "Luke Shi"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Zobu hu",
        "title": "engineer",
        "direct Report": "Tom Las"
    }
]

Leader={}
Team=defaultdict(list)

for line in MemberInfo:
    if "direct Report" not in line and line['UserName'] not in Leader:
        Leader[line['UserName']] = line['title']
    elif line['direct Report']:
        Team[line['direct Report']].append(line['UserName'])

for key,value in Leader.iteritems():
    print("{} - {}".format(key,value))
    for Member in Team[key]:
        if Member in Team:
            print("  {}".format(Member))
            print(" "*4 + ' '.join(Team[Member]))
        else:
            print("  {}".format(Member))
```

Comment: What about trees?

Comment: You could have used a nested dictionary. That way you could insert a report under the appropriate place in the heirarchy. The root would have Both Tom Las and Mike Sea underneath it directly

Comment: The interviewer appears not to know what "direct report" means.

Comment: @tdelaney, that is my fault. I can't recall the exact keyword they were using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a tree... I changed "direct reports" to "manager" since I think the point is to name the person's manager in the `MemberInfo` object. The reverse link of a manager is a list of direct reports, so that's what I setup in the example below. I started by indexing the list, addied a `"direct reports"` list and then filled out that list. Then it was just a question of a recursive routine that would print and entry followed by any direct reports. The code makes no assumptions about how bloated the organization is, but does assume that there are no loops in the list... I once reported to myself at a job I had and that played havoc with all sorts of software. Interestingly, I was working on code that managed Active Directory `Manager` and `directReports` fields at the time.

```
MemberInfo = [
    {
        "UserName": "Tom Las",
        "title": "Director"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Mike Sea",
        "title": "senior manager"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Jojo Lee",
        "title": "manager",
        "Manager": "Mike Sea"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Luke Shi",
        "title": "manager",
        "Manager": "Mike Sea"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Bob Aeo",
        "title": "engineer",
        "Manager": "Luke Shi"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Zobu hu",
        "title": "engineer",
        "Manager": "Tom Las"
    }
]

def crawl_ranks(name, indent=''):
    """Prints member and direct report names recursively"""
    member = member_index[name]
    print('{}{}'.format(indent, member['UserName']))
    for name in sorted(member.get('direct reports', [])):
        crawl_ranks(name, indent=indent + '  ')

# index by name for easy lookup
member_index = {member['UserName']:member for member in MemberInfo}

# add direct reports list to member info
for member in MemberInfo:
    member['direct reports'] = []

# add dummy index entry for bossless persons
member_index[None] = {'direct reports':[]}

# add member name to boss's direct reports list
for member in MemberInfo:
    member_index[member.get('Manager')]['direct reports'].append(member['UserName'])

# print, starting with top-level managers
for name in sorted(member_index[None]['direct reports']):
    crawl_ranks(name)
```

Comment: Beautiful! tree structure is way more flexible and indent in format is so convenient!!